# USA Contiguous Albers Equal Area Conic

Tags: distance, coordinates, latitude-longitude

How do you convert from USA Contiguous Albers Equal Area Conic to meters?  Or, to latitude and longitude?

I am using ArcGIS 10.1, and within it, ArcMap.  The shapefile I have reports the coordinates as USA Contiguous Albers Equal Area Conic.  I want to take areas and distances of the polygons and they are very large due to the units.  I am wondering how to convert to meters.

In particular, I want to do distance calculations, and I worry that Albers distorts the distances.  How can get the most precise and meaningful distances when the shapefile orginated as Albers Equal Conic?

The shapefile is of United States counties.  I would like to compute its distances within it.

Comment: What software are you using?  Do you want to convert a list of coordinates or actual geometry?

Comment: Without knowing more about your problem, you may want to have a look at [this site](http://georepository.com/calculator/). It will help you convert between coordinate systems.

Answer (score 3):

The coordinate system, USA Contiguous Albers equal area conic, by default is in meters, so any calculations you do should be in meters or square meters. Depending on how large the polygons are, the values could be very large. Did you want to have the values reported in kilometers instead? The Calculate Geometry tool lets you choose a different unit value.

In the ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1 help, the help topic is in Geodata, Data types, Tables, Calculating field values, [Calculating area, length, and other geometric properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000027000000).

There's a small chance that someone modified the USA Contiguous Albers definition and changed the units. You can check this by looking at the coordinate system of the layer in ArcMap or ArcCatalog.

Comment: How would I recover the latitude and longitude from these units?  The distance I understand.  Is this what you are saying to do in ArcMap or ArcCatalog?  I am using ArcMap.  What exactly would you suggest that I do?  Is it by looking at the Attributes Table?  That is where I discovered that the coordinates did not look like latitude or longitude for the United States!!

Comment: You can use Calculate Geometry to add the centroid or min or max coordinate values to an attribute table. One way is to open the attribute table in Arcmap. Set the data frame to use NAD 1983 (in geographic coord systems, N Amer) then you can choose for the coords to be in lat/lon. Or use the Project Tool to create a copy in the NAD 1983 system.

Comment: Thank you!  Sorry, but how would one set the data frame to use NAD 1983?  I've been looking at the Table of Contents part of the ArcMap screen, and I am not finding this option.

Comment: Also, is there a particular version of NAD 1983 that should be used?  Googling around there seems to be a few.  Like NAD 1983 (2011), NAD 1983 HARN, NAD 1983 (CSRS), NAD 1983, among others.

Comment: Right click Layers in the TOC or in the map itself and select Properties from the context menu. In the data frame properties dialog, select the coordinate systems tab. I would just use NAD 1983.

Comment: Thank you, that made complete sense!  I think I changed the coordinates successfully.  However, I am still not able to see the latitude and longitude.  When I go to the Attribute Table, I have 2 variables called X_Centroid and Y_Centroid.  I suspect these came with the shapefile and were not a calculation done by GIS.  For counties in MA, they are reporting numbers like 1951227, 792045 for the centroid for once of the counties.  I am wondering what the latitude, longitude analog is.  I imagine the numbers don't affect distance and area calculations though because it goes straight to meters?

Comment: They're likely the coordinate values in Albers (in meters). You could re-calculate the field values, or add new double precision fields and then calculate the centroids in lat/lon.

Comment: May I just confirm that the distance between two polygons in the Abers is indeed in meters?  I did not know if gets all distorted in the projection.

Comment: If you don't override the units in whatever method you're using to calculate the distance, yes, they'll be in meters. Distances are distorted in Albers, but how much will depend on where the two points are located. How you calculate the distance though could use different algorithms. Default (in ArcGIS) is usually 2D Cartesian which will include any distortion due to the projection.

Comment: And, I have to say, I think my answer does still fit the question, so unmarking it as an accepted answer seems...unfair. Update the question to include a bunch of these comments and I'll try to update the question to match. Or at least please describe how it doesn't answer the question as stated. Thanks!

Comment: Would you recommend projecting?  If so, how?  I have the shapefile as a feature (?) of points, one for each county.  I tried projecting, but I'm not sure if I did it correctly.  What exactly should happen afterwards?  Should new cells be created?  Should values change?

Comment: Projections can be really confusing. When you (re)project a feature, the coordinate values will change to match the output coordinate system (projection). The attribute table, which may list coordinate values, will not change. So any fields in the attribute table that contain coordinates may need to be updated if you want to see the current coordinate system values. To change coordinate system, use the Project Tool, which will create a copy of the data.

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly are you recommending:  Are you saying not to project?  Or are you saying to change the coordinate system?

Comment: My apologies about unaccepting the answer (for the moment). I was not sure how to get your attention for this follow up. I updated the question. I hope the concern I have is clear. Thank you very much for all of your patience and time